# How do I hide a table row element based on a condition

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, hide

I have a table with the fields 'TotalNumber' and 'TotalConfirmed' on each row.  The row also has a Percentage field whose value is calculated in the report query, and a field with an asterisk if that percentage value is below a certain value.  I want to add a summary column with sum of TotalNumber and TotalConfirmed (done), a calculation of the overall Percentage (done), and then an Asterisk in the column if the overall Percentage is below a certain value.  I've tried a conditional hide on the item, using 
`=(ReportItems!NumConfirmed1.Value / ReportItems!NumOffenders1.Value) >= 0.65`
and having an Asterisk show in the box by default, but it doesn't show for values above or below the cutoff.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iif(cdbl(ReportItems!NumConfirmed1.Value / ReportItems!NumOffenders1.Value)>=0.65,true,false)

Comment: Not doing it.  I'm still missing something.  What other information would be helpful to show what's happening (or not happening)?